# Why is a hidden function is using derived class variable?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

This is a very basic program but I thought it is necessary to get my doubt cleared.

The output of the below program is **disp in base, x = 100**.

In the below program, I am only setting the value of `x` in derived class object, which in turn is inheriting it from the base class. In base class `x` is being intialized with the value `10`. What I failed to understand is that when I call the function `disp` using the syntax **d1.base::disp()** how does it takes the value of `x` from the derived class into the function of base class? I am expecting it to display `10` in place of `x`.

Is there some concept that I am missing here?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base {
public:
    int x = 10;
    void disp() { 
        cout<< "disp in base, x = " << x << endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    void disp() {
        cout<< "disp in derived, x = " << x << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    derived d1;
    d1.x = 100;
    d1.base::disp();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x` is in the base class, not the derived one. So I don't understand the question.

Comment: an instance of `derived` gets it `x` via "has-a" from `derived`'s base class, `base`. There is no magic here. What other `x` were you expecting?

Comment: "_Here I am only setting the value of x in derived class object_": The derived class has no direct `x` member. `d1.x` refers to the `x` in the base class subobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there some concept that I am missing here?*

Yes. Although your derived class `disp()` function hides the function with the same signature in the base class, it uses **the same `x` member variable as the base class**. This is the way inheritance works: functions and data that are not overridden (or hidden) by a derived class are *inherited* from the base class; internally, a `derived` object will have, as part of its memory layout, an *actual* `base` object, and the class will have access to the members of that base class, if the relevant access attribute (i.e. `protected` or `public`, but not `private`) is given to those members.

In your code, the derived class doesn't also hide/shadow that base class `x` member, so it uses the same variable. For the derived and base classes to have separate (i.e. different) `x` members, you would need to also declare that member in the derived class, like below:

```cpp
class derived : public base {
public:
    int x = 10; // Gives "derived" its own "x", which hides the base class member
    void disp() {
        cout << "disp in derived, x = " << x << endl;
    }
};
```

With that modification, your `d1.base::disp();` call will display the `10`, which is the (unmodified) value of the base class member variable, because the `d1.x = 100;` line now modifies the *entirely different* `x` member of the derived class.

Note that hiding such data members is considered bad practice by many C++ programmers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can figure out if you were to add the following line in your main method,

```
d1.disp();
```

You will get the following output,

```
disp in base, x = 100
disp in derived, x = 100
```

From what I can figure out is because the variable x in your base class is public, the derived class inherits that variable. Therefor, when you .setX to a value, you change that variable in the derived class which is the same as within the base class. Which is what I could figure out.